# pagestyle of multipage tableofcontents with scrbook class?

Tags: table-of-contents, scrbook, scrlayer-scrpage

I'm using scrbook class with a frontmatter and mainmatter and I've adjusted the contents of my headings using `\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}`.

Just like I wanted, the first page of the Contents has a plain pagestyle (roman numeral page number at the bottom)  But my problem was on the **second page of the Contents: It has a Chapter heading at top**, and a roman numeral page number at the bottom.   `\tableofcontents` is supposed to generate entirely `\pagestyle{plain}` type page numbers, even when the contents span two or more pages.  Is that correct?

I've fixed it by manually adding `\pagestyle{plain}\tableofcontents` and then adding \mainmatter\pagestyle{scrheadings} afterwards, to get plain Contents pages on both, and then revert to headers and footers on for the mainmatter chapters (except the first chapter pages which are plain, of course).

So, I just want to know if I've broken something in preamble to cause `\tableofcontents` to misbehave, or if what I'm experiencing normal behavior of the `\tableofcontents`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the expected behavior. The first page of the Contents is a chapter page, so it uses pagestyle `plain`. The second page is "normal" page and uses the current pagestyle, e.g. `scrheadings`.

To set pagestyle `plain` for the whole `Contents` you can use

```
\AfterTOCHead[toc]{\pagestyle{plain}}
\AfterStartingTOC[toc]{\clearpage}
```

If this should be done also for all lists controlled by KOMA-Script package `tocbasic` (like List of Figures or List of Tables), remove the optional argument:

```
\AfterTOCHead{\pagestyle{plain}}
\AfterStartingTOC{\clearpage}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets automatically `\pagestyle{scrheadings}`

\AfterTOCHead{\pagestyle{plain}}
\AfterStartingTOC{\clearpage}

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}
\Blindtext
\mainmatter
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: That works perfectly.  But I'm trying to understand why the second line: "\AfterStartingTOC{\clearpage}" is necessary?  It see that it's definitely necessary, but don't understand why.  What's the command doing?

Comment: `\AfterStartingTOC{\clearpage}` sets a `\clearpage` before the scope using `\pagestyle{plain}` is closed. So the last page of your TOC uses `\pagestyle{plain}` too.